# Oracle- Need some changes to the Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below Query. My Expected output would be as below. Please help me make changes to the Query

```
select 
ID,TERM,
case
  when TERM  like '____1_' then
     function_toget_hrs(ID, TERM,sysdate) else null
    end fall_hours,
 case 
   when TERM  like '____2_' then
      function_toget_hrs(ID, TERM,sysdate) else null
    end winter_hours
  
    from TABLE_TERM
    where ID='12087762'
```

[image: Actual Result]

Expecting one row for each ID. Please help me the ways

Comment: What values are you expecting to see in the other 3 columns?

Comment: Isn't it working as it is? what is it producing? How do we know what is wrong?

Comment: It is working but the User want to have one row for each Id.   I am thinking of using a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivoting is what you need:

```
WITH TABLE_TERM AS
(
  SELECT 12087762 AS ID, '202110____1_' AS term, 12 AS func FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 12087762 AS ID, '202120____2_' AS term, 16 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 12087762 AS ID, '202140____1_' AS term, 0  FROM dual 
)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ID
             , DECODE(SUBSTR(term,-6),'____1_','fall_hours','winter_hours') AS hrs
             , func --function_toget_hrs(ID, TERM,sysdate) for test purposes
          FROM TABLE_TERM
         WHERE ID =  '12087762'
        )
  PIVOT (SUM(func) FOR hrs IN ('fall_hours','winter_hours'));
```

Comment: @Gnqz- I changed a little bit to your query. It is working. Thankyou!